# What happens on a tie on minBy / maxBy functions?

Tags: kotlin, math, max, min

If you run a `minBy` or `maxBy` from the [kotlin-stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/) on a collection with two objects and there's a tie for the lowest / highest value, which one will the function return?

Comment: It's literally the first thing the doc says: *Returns the first element yielding the largest value of the given function*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of both [minBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by.html) and [maxBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html) state:

> Returns the first entry yielding the (smallest / largest) value ...

The behaviour is clearly defined and part of the API contract, and thus can be relied upon.

---

You have run your own experiments to come to the same conclusion. A word of caution though:

While running experiments to determine the behaviour of third party code can work, you should be aware, that the result from an experiment like this is far from being a proof.
Assuming the behaviour was not defined in the API contract, a new release of the third party library might change this behaviour at any time.

Additionally, there might be edge cases, in which the result differs from the observation your experiment yielded, just because it has not run into this edge case.
A stupid but simplified example, which your experiments most likely wouldn't have observed the different behaviour:

```kotlin
fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.minBy(
    selector: (T) -> R
): T {
   val returnLastMatch = random.nextInt() % 1_000_000 == 0

   ...

   if(returnLastMatch) {
      lastMatch
   } else firstMatch
}
```

If a behaviour is not specified in the API contract but you still want to rely on it, I'd rather analyze the source code, if it's available, to ensure a function works as expected, to avoid pitfalls like aforementioned.

In general **I'd recommend to not rely on behaviour, that's not clearly defined in an API contract**. Luckily for you, the behaviour of both `minBy` and `maxBy` is clearly defined regarding your case.

Answer (score -2):

Of the tied objects, it will return the first one it encounters in the list.  See this Kotlin playground for to see how it works: https://pl.kotl.in/aapJRHy0Q

Comment: Why are you even asking the question if you answered yourself in the same second?

Comment: I couldn't find an answer on here or in the documentation, I ran an experiment to figure it out and now when someone searches for this question they'll find the answer.  Go to the question ask form, there's a checkbox to answer your own question, its definitely expected behavior.

Comment: Self-answering may be useful for questions that other people may ask themselves and have trouble finding answers to, for posterity. In this specific case, the doc is a single sentence to read and has the answer right in it, so I don't think this is useful. I don't mean to undermine the effort, but if you find the doc unclear, I think it would be more useful to open a PR with a wording change, rather than adding a self-answered question to SO.